# WinAPi OpenGL Borderless Fullscreen - Alt Tab problems

Tags: opengl, c++, winapi

I'm implementing a borderless fullscreen functionality and managed to make something that almost works. Using: C++, Winapi, OpenGL 3.3.

When  in fullscreen borderless mode, if alt tab the game window loses focus but is still on top, not even the alt tab window shows.

I managed to track it down to SwapBuffers. If i disable it, no problems but also no rendering.

If i force the window to hide when it loses focus, the entire screen flickers. And if i alt tab back, only the game window flickers.

If i put the game in windowed mode, it works as normal.

Window Styles are first set to(windowed mode stops  here):

```
WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE
```

And then are set to(if fullscreen):

```
GetWindowLong(window, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
```

My gameloop:

```
while(isRunning)
{
    loopNewTime = timeGetTime();
    loopDuration = (r32)(loopNewTime - loopOldTime);
    loopTime = Clamp(0.0f, (loopDuration - sleepTime), 250.0f);

    loopOldTime = loopNewTime;
    loopAccumulator += loopTime + sleepTime;

    while(loopAccumulator >= loopFixedDeltaTime)
    {
        if(isFocused || canRunWithoutFocus)
        {
            DoStuff();
        }

        loopAccumulator -= loopFixedDeltaTime;
    }

    if(isFocused || canRunWithoutFocus)
    {
        DoStuff();

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

        DrawStuff();

        SwapBuffers(deviceContext);
    }



    framerateTimeThreshhold += loopTime + sleepTime;
    ++framerateCount;

    if(framerateTimeThreshhold >= 1)
    {
        framerate = framerateCount;
        framerateCount = 0;
        --framerateTimeThreshhold;
    }

    sleepTime = Max(timeStep - loopTime, 0.0f);

    Sleep((u32)sleepTime);
}
```

So, how can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To anyone with this problem, i found a 99% perfect answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145217/flickering-when-borderless-window-and-desktop-dimensions-are-the-same

What i did: Set the window size to the size of the screen + 1. For some reason if window and screen are the same size, Windows reacts like a normal fullscreen.

Comment: Post that as an answer

Comment: If you take away WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW maybe there's no style left - have you tried setting the WS_POPUP style? SetWindowLong(window, GWL_STYLE, (GetWindowLong(window, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW) | WS_POPUP);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone with this problem, i found a 99% perfect answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145217/flickering-when-borderless-window-and-desktop-dimensions-are-the-same

What i did: Set the window size to the size of the screen + 1. For some reason if the window and the screen are the same size Windows will act like it's a "normal" fullscreen.